# Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n > 1$. Prove that $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: equivalence-relations, formal-proofs

For reflexive: Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means $a \equiv a(mod n)$, which can be written as $n\mid a-a$. There is an integer $k$ such that $a-a=nk$.

I know we need to find if there is a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for integer $a$, when $a-a=nk$. I know $k$ must be zero for this to be true, but I'm not sure how to write the proof.

For symmetric: Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. This means when $a\equiv b(mod n)$, then $a-b=nk$ for some integer $k$, so $b-a=nr$ for some integer $r$ and hence $b\equiv a(mod n)$.

Again I'm not sure how to write the proof.

For transitive: Let $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Z}$. This means when $a\equiv b(mod n)$, then $a-b=nk$ for some integer $k$. We also know $b\equiv c(mod n)$, so $b-c=nm$ for some integer $m$. There must be some integer $r$ such that $a-c=nr$.

Answer (score 1):

For symmetry

Let $ (a,b)\in \Bbb Z^2.$

$$a\equiv b \mod n \implies$$

$$\exists k\in \Bbb Z \;\; : \;\; a-b=kn \implies$$

$$\exists k\in \Bbb Z \;: b-a=(-k)n \implies $$
$$\exists r(=-k) \in \Bbb Z \;\;:\; b-a=rn \implies$$

$$b\equiv a \mod n$$

For the transitivity, observe that
$$(a-b) + (b-c) = (a-c)$$